# В чём сложность взлома сайтов?

Tags: безопасность

Создал регистрацию на сайте, есть в БД всякие коды определенных пользователей. 
Есть ли смысл от регистрации. Если злодей может перехватывать пакеты и смотреть что в них?
Из-за чего это выполнить невозможно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Злоумышленник должен знать куда слать(хост), кому слать(имя пользователя) и чего слать (БД плюс пароль) - это как минимум, чтобы создать соединение. Угадать случайно такую комбинацию можно, но больше шансов выиграть в лотерею. Далее, если пароли хранятся в МД5 понадобится ещё немного везения(или навыков) и тогда возможно ему удастся подобрать парочку чужих паролей.

Comment: Ну когда н-р пользователь регистрируется, нажимает кнопку отправить и через какую-нибудь программу перехватывает пакет. 
Расскрывает его и обнаруживает пароль к БД, имя пользователя и т.п.

Comment: Представляю себе его лицо, когда он

>> Расскрывает его и обнаруживает пароль к БД, имя пользователя и т.п.

![йобанаврот](http://ememdem.net/uploads/images/00/00/18/2012/02/17/fc9e8f.jpg)

Comment: Я в макдаке баловался с помощью droidsheep) Сообщения в контактике читаются на ура.

Comment: @lampa, одно дело перехватывать открытые пакеты из воздуха и совсем другое сделать невозможное не имея квантового компа

Answer (score 2):

> HTTPS (HyperText Transfer Protocol
> Secure) — расширение протокола HTTP,
> поддерживающее шифрование. Данные,
> передаваемые по протоколу HTTPS,
> «упаковываются» в криптографический
> протокол SSL или TLS, тем самым
> обеспечивается защита этих данных. В
> отличие от HTTP, для HTTPS по
> умолчанию используется TCP-порт 443.